# Could not find column with id ... in mat-table angular

Tags: angular

I am begginer in angular, my html is:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="list_models" matSort style="width: 100%;"> 
          <!-- id Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id" style="width: 20%;">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center !important;" mat-sort-header> id</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_models" style="text-align: center;"> {{list_models.id}} </td>
          </ng-container>
           <!-- CaptionCode Column -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center !important;" mat-sort-header> description </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_models" style="text-align: center;"> {{list_models.description}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- MDesc Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="MDesc">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center !important;" mat-sort-header> model</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_models" style="text-align: center;"> {{list_models.MDesc}} </td>
          </ng-container>
            <!-- CaptionCode Column -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="BDesc">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center !important;" mat-sort-header> brand </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_models" style="text-align: center;"> {{list_models.BDesc}} </td>
          </ng-container>
```

and in ts code is :

```
public list_models = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
displayedColumnsModel: string[] = ['id','description','MDesc','BDesc','action'];
    
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.get_data_Model();
}
    
get_data_Model(){
   this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listmodels").subscribe(
      res => this.list_models.data = res
   );
}
```

and in node i have this code:

```
app.get("/listmodels",(req,res)=>{
   const sqlQuery="SELECT 
modeltbl.id,modeltbl.MDesc,brandtbl.BDesc,captiontbl.description FROM ((modeltbl INNER JOIN brandtbl ON modeltbl.brandcode = brandtbl.id) INNER JOIN captiontbl ON modeltbl.captioncode = captiontbl.id)";
console.log(sqlQuery);
   ConnectToDB().query(sqlQuery,(err,rows,fields)=>{
      if(err){
         console.log("error connecting to DB" + err)
         res.sendStatus(500);
         return
      }
      res.json(rows);
   });
});
```

The problem is that in the browser console I have this error:
Could not find the column with id "MDesc"
please help me, Apparently, everything is right.

Answer (score 0):

you have assigned the response from the  `this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listmodels")` to `this.list_models.data` as below

```
this.list_models.data = res
```

and in your HTML you are accessing your data with `list_models.id` so the issue is clear either change your response assignment to

```
this.list_models = res
```

or you can change your HTML `list_models.MDesc` to `list_models.data.MDesc`